# Microsoft Access Data Base .. Select Query

Tags: ms-access

i am doing queries practice in Microsoft access. i want to concatenate the first name with the fax number.. the fax number is like (123)555-0103 .. 
i`m doing that

```
select [first name] +' ''s Fax Number is' +str(fax number) as [Mariya`s Fax Number] 
from employees where id =4;
```

but it is giving error..

Comment: Please show us the error its giving

Comment: syntax error(missing operator) in query expression'[first name] +' ''s Fax number is' +str(fax number)'.

Comment: Google for "access combine strings": http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/concat.php
It says: "string" & "another" outputs "stringanother"

Comment: Use the & concatenation operator and you won't need to coerce the fax number to string data type. The in Jet/ACE SQL and VBA, the + operator propagates Nulls for non-numeric data, but performs addition for numbers. In Access, use the & for concatenation by default and use the + for concatenation only when you want to propagate Nulls (e.g., Mid(("12"+LastName) & (", "+FirstName), 3) to get "Fenton, David" for names).

Answer (score 1):

That would be:

```
select [first name] & " ''s Fax Number is " & [fax number] as [Mariya`s Fax Number] 
from employees where id =4
```

You should use & to concatenate
You should use '' for each single quote
You should use double quotes (") for strings.

Comment: One should use & for concatenation when you don't want to propagate Nulls. If [fax number] is non-numeric, the + concatenation operator will give you just the first name when the fax number is Null, whereas with & you'll get "FirstName's Fax Number is ", which is probably not acceptable. Phone numbers really oughtn't ever be stored as numbers, so it's likely to work just fine with [FirstName] & ("'s Fax Number is"+[FaxNumber]).